# FTP Mirroring in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

We maintain over 70 property websites on a single CI application fueled by a database (actually, one database and application for production sites and one database and application for development sites) to provide the necessary differences for each site. We provide a custom CMS so that the property managers can update their site regularly. There is an approval process to push changes made to their development site through the CMS to their production site.

One CMS function is to upload photo albums. Once the album is uploaded on development and approved for production, I need to copy this folder from the development assets to their production assets.

I establish the FTP connection and create the photo album folder without issue using:

```
$this->ftp->mkdir($path['ftpP'].'photoAlbums/'.$album[0]['albumFolderName'].'/', DIR_WRITE_MODE);
```

($path[‘ftpP’] looks like this: /httpdocs/edrAssets/propsP/700/

When I try to use the mirror function in the FTP class, I don’t get any errors or warnings but I also don’t get any transfer—- just nothing.

Here is that code:

```
$dLink = $path['ftpD'].'photoAlbums/'.$album[0]['albumFolderName'].'/';
$pLink = $path['ftpP'].'photoAlbums/'.$album[0]['albumFolderName'].'/';

$this->ftp->mirror($dLink, $pLink);
```

I have been fighting this since late Thursday night and need some advice. ALL help is appreciated.

Jon

REQUESTED LOG FILE:

DEBUG - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Controller Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Ftp class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.

DEBUG - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Trying to FTP here

ERROR - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Severity: Warning  --> opendir() [function.opendir]: Unable to access /httpdocs/edrAssets/propsD/700/photoAlbums/theUSOpen2012/ /var/www/vhosts/edrpropertyoperations.com/httpdocs/WEBdev/system/libraries/Ftp.php 532

ERROR - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Severity: Warning  --> opendir(/httpdocs/edrAssets/propsD/700/photoAlbums/theUSOpen2012/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory /var/www/vhosts/edrpropertyoperations.com/httpdocs/WEBdev/system/libraries/Ftp.php 532

DEBUG - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Final output sent to browser

DEBUG - 2012-06-18 07:15:31 --> Total execution time: 0.1626

ADDED *******

```
    public function approved_create_album( $id ){   
         $thisTask = $this->mcms->getSingleAdminTask( $id );

         $album = $this->mcms->getAlbumByID($thisTask[0]['itemID']);    
         $path = $this->mcms->path_variables( $album[0]['propNumber']);

         $this->load->library('ftp');   
         $ftp['hostname'] = <REMOVED>;
         $ftp['username'] = <REMOVED>;  
         $ftp['password'] = <REMOVED>;
         $ftp['port']     = 21;     
         $ftp['passive']  = FALSE;  
         $ftp['debug']    = TRUE;   
         $ftp['ssl_mode'] = FALSE;  
         $this->ftp->connect($ftp);

         $dLink = $path['ftpD'].'photoAlbums/'.$album[0]['albumFolderName'].'/';    
         $pLink = $path['ftpP'].'photoAlbums/'.$album[0]['albumFolderName'].'/';

         if( !file_exists($pLink) && !is_dir($pLink)){
              $this->ftp->mkdir($path['ftpP'].'photoAlbums/'.$album[0]['albumFolderName'].'/', DIR_WRITE_MODE);     
         } // end if

         log_message('debug', 'Trying to FTP here');
         $this->ftp->mirror($dLink, $pLink);

         echo $dLink . " to " . $pLink; 
} // end approved_create_album function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest step-by-step debugging:

1) Set debug to TRUE,see [function reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html). You may need to turn [error_reporting](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) on.

2) Connect to the server (which you did) and upload a file.
If that works you know that a) the connection works and b) you've got the filepath right.

If it still doesn't work, look through the logs (or post them here ;-)).
Good luck!

**Update:**

I tested the FTP library on my own servers. Works like a charm, straight out of the box. So we need to firure out if the problem is with the servers or with your CI configuration.

Here's what I would do next:

1) Try less configuration, less variables, hardcode everything using this example:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('ftp');
$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username'; 
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$this->ftp->connect($config);
$this->ftp->mirror('/path/to/myfolder/', '/public_html/myfolder/');
$this->ftp->close();
```

If it doesn't work, then:

2) Download a fresh CI installation and put it on your server. You won't need any configuration or DB connections. Then try the example above in the fresh enviroment.

Comment: How about step 2) ? Could you upload a file?

Comment: Could you also add the following to your code and update the log. Then we can see where your code is executed. log_message('debug', 'Trying to FTP here');  I also see that the FTP class is being loaded 2 times. That could be the problem if it's rewriting your settings (even though it says that it's being ignored)

Comment: I added the log above ... something is happening now that I added that code

Comment: I also added the complete controller method above

Comment: You accepted the answer. Is the problem resolved? I haven't had time yet to look into your log.

Comment: No, unfortunately, the problem is not resolved. I accepted your answer because it taught me about dubug messages (thanks for that ... what a tool that I haven't been using -- until now).

Comment: The "now" issue is that open_dir doesn't recognize the source, so the mirror function fails. But if I look at the site in Cyberduck (ftp program), the folder is definitely there and with 777 permission. I even extended the ftp class and wrote my own version of "mirror" as a recursive function but for some reason, the source folder is never recognized and produces the same error. Since this is such an integral piece of the CMS, I have to find out why codeigniter won't see a folder that cyberduck can. If you have any thoughts, I would covet them. Thanks for caring!!!

Answer (score 0):

What about just dropping down to unix in your code and using command line `rsync`.